# IPC between Credential Provider and a system service

Tags: c++, windows-7, credentials, credential-providers

What is the best way to communicate with a custom Credential Provider from a system service ?
Is it possible to send a message through the message pump ?
Can I use named pipes ?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credential provider runs in the session of the user, while the system service runs in the system session. As far as I know, this rules out Windows Messages. Messages also requires a window to be created and the process having a message pump, which a service normally doesn't have.

I would suggest named pipes. The system service can create the pipe and listen to it. Any instance of the credential provider attaches and then can messages be sent.

Comment: Not all credential providers are called in the session of the user. Looking at my expirience, in workstation logon, unlock scenarios (and password change scenario during logon or unlock) and in UAC scenario, credential provider get called by LogonUI.exe and Consent.exe accordingly, with LocalSystem rights. In scenarios with remote desktop connection and network shared resources viewing scenarion, credential provider get called by mstsc.exe and explorer.exe accordingly, with rights of currently logged user.